# How to make duplicates of values in a list python

Tags: python

Quick question... searched and didn't find anything. I have this list:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

I want to have each value repeated 3 more times in the same list... How do I do so?  I tried some for loops that .append to the list but things got messy. I ended up getting some list in list that were in lists. I have a feeling .append is not right for this scenario.

Comment: [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,]  Basically 4 more of everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested loops in a list comprehension.

```
>>> [x for x in L for y in range(4)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

In [2]: sorted(my_list * 3)
```

Note that you should not use `list` as a variable name, because it shadows the keyword `list`.

One other option is to use `numpy`:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: np.repeat(my_list, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this!

```
baselist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
[z for y in [[x]*4 for x in baselist] for z in y]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
listofLists = []
for x in baseList:
    listofLists.append([x]*4)

finalList = []
for y in listofLists:
    for z in y:
        finalList.append(z)
```

You see, the list comprehension simply shortens the logic, but whether it's more readable will depend on your grasp of comprehension syntax.

Comment: Sweeeet, thanks everyone for the fast replies... I was trying some list comprehensions too but I was doing them all wrong.

Comment: @tear728 I recommend you choose Avinash Raj's or Ignacio's answer on this one. Their solutions make a lot more sense from all perspectives (efficiency, readability, etc). Thank you, though!

Comment: Eithos I used yours but I did not end up getting the desired answer =[  I got   [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10] notice four 1's , 20 10's and 5 of everything else! Thanks anyways though!

Comment: @tear728 You should double-check that you've entered it correctly. I've just run through it again to be sure, and it gives exactly the right output (4x everything). The only explanation I can think of is you used `*5` instead of `*4` and somehow removed one of the `1`s. I don't mind that you went with Avinash's answer, but this one works exactly like you asked, too.

Comment: you are totally right, I just found the bug, what you had works too. Thanks again for the hep!

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this,

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
>>> [j for i in lst for j in [i,i,i,i]]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Great solution! This is how you should write the list comp if that's the way you choose to go @tear728. +1

Comment: Actually Ignacio's answer is better in that (a) it doesn't require repeatedly creating and destroying sub-lists and (b) it makes it really easy to vary how many times each item gets copied - it stores it explicitly as a number instead of implicitly as sub-list structure.

Comment: @HughBothwell Agreed. I didn't notice it until now... :0

Answer (score 0):

Another `itertools` variation using the [`flatten` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(m,m,m,m)))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
>>>
```